# How to code this specific for loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have created an average word length checker in Python and I want to convert it into Java.

This is the for loop in Python:

```py
for p in "!£$€%^&*()-_=+`¬¦[]{};:'@#~,.<>/?|":

        sentence = sentence.replace(p, '')

    words = sentence.split()
```

I want to code this in Java.

Here is what I've tried in Java:

```java
public class AverageWordLength {

    public void average_word_length(String sentence){
        String characters = "!£$€%^&*()-_=+`¬¦[]{};:'@#~,.<>/?|"

        for (char p: characters){
            
        }
    }
```

Any hints on how to do this?

Comment: When converting code from one language to another, usually you want to convert _functionality_ and not convert the code line by line.  Some stuff makes sense in one language but not another.  Additionally, you should post what you tried in Java

Comment: store this `!£$€%^&*()-_=+`¬¦[]{};:'@#~,.<>/?| in a string variable and interate it with a for each `for(char c: myString)`

Comment: @Nexevis Yes I understand what you mean, and that is exactly what I meant, "convert functionality". Here is what I have tried: 
public class AverageWordLength {

    public void average_word_length(String sentence){
        for (String p in "!£$€%^&*()-_=+`¬¦[]{};:'@#~,.<>/?|"){

            sentence = sentence.split();
        
        String words = sentence.split()
        }


    }
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edit your question with the Java code, don't post it in a comment

Comment: var words = sentence.replaceAll("[^\\w]+"," ").split(" ");

Comment: @ChristophDahlen A shorter way to write that is `replaceAll("\\W+", " ")`.

Answer (score 0):

String has a split method to split a string with a regular expression
With the stream method the array is converted in a stream.
With the map for each part the length is calculated
And at last the collect returns the average of the length

```
public class WordLengthChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(average_word_length("String_to_split[on(special]characters") );
    }

    public static double average_word_length(String sentence){
        String characters = "[!£$€%^&*()\\-_=+`¬¦\\[\\]{};:'@#~,.<>/?|]";
        return Arrays.stream(sentence.split(characters))
                .map(i -> i.length())
                .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(i -> i));

    }
}
```

.